# Property 'querySelector' does not exist on type 'Node'. in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:
test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="zh-CN">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the ts file test.ts

```
var box = document.querySelector('#box');
console.log(box.parentNode.querySelector('#box'));
```

and i got the error.

```
Error:(2, 28) TS2339: Property 'querySelector' does not exist on type 'Node'.
```

I found the following sentence in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

**parentNode is the parent of the current node. The parent of an element is an Element node, a Document node, or a DocumentFragment node.**

here is my test

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul')
undefined
ul.parentNode.toString()
[object HTMLDivElement]"
```

could someone tell me what's wrong with that?

the version of typescript is 1.4

Answer (score 25):

For those looking for a solution using Typescript and JSX (**.tsx**):

```
const box = document.querySelector('#box');
console.log((box.parentNode as HTMLElement).querySelector('#box'));
```

Answer (score 24):

> could someone tell me what's wrong with that

TypeScript's view of the API. At the moment there is no way to say that the type of `foo.parentNode` depends on the type of `foo`. Currently it is inferred to always be of type `Node` and `Node` does not contain the API `querySelector` (available on `Element`)

## Fix

Use a type assertion as shown:

```
var box = document.querySelector('#box');
console.log((<Element>box.parentNode).querySelector('#box'));
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone encountering this problem with React Hooks / tsx, I updated my declaration of useRef with `as HTMLElement | null`, then I could use optional chaining without error.

```
const formRef = useRef(null as HTMLElement | null);

const form = formRef?.current?.querySelector('form');
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
let box = <Element>document.querySelector('#box');
```

Answer (score 0):

The parentNode member returns the parent node, which can be of type Element or Node. You have to use parentElement to traverse DOM tree instead of parentNode which traverse XML tree.

```
var box = document.querySelector('#box');

console.log(box.parentElement.querySelector('#box'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using `create-react-app` `2.1`'s TS setup.

For me it was a matter of adding `dom` to the `lib` list in `tsconfig.json`.

```
"lib": [..., "dom"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@ts-check` inside .js file, there is a clean solution for you – just check if a node is an instance of `Element` or whatever it should be:

```js
const box = document.querySelector('#box');
const parentNode = box?.parentNode;

if (!(parentNode instanceof Element)) {
  throw new Error('box.parentNode is not an Element');
}

console.log(parentNode.querySelector('#box'));
```